Создание браузерного проводника
Хотел бы узнать, можно ли реализовать с помощью python (или подключения html/css) так называемый "серверный браузер"? То есть на локальном хосте либо же на странице html будет некий "проводник", отображаемый файлы в определенной директории. В дальнейшем добавить взаимодействие с этими файлами

Главное здесь - получить список файлов и каталогов в заданном каталоге. Получение такого списка может осуществляться откуда угодно, в том числе и с рабочего места пользователя. А дальше интерфейс подачи списка и его обработки - по вкусу, самое простое - ttk.Treeview.

можно, но сервер нужно запустить на том же компе где находится эта директория.
